# Drawing circle inside UIView frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I'd like to draw a circle inside UITableViewCell.

To make it easier with positioning, I decided to place UIView using interface builder, set constraints, and then draw the circle from code inside this UIView.

This is how it's supposed to look like:
[image]

However, I had a problem with drawing the circle right in the middle of the square view. I figured out this solution, but to me it looks more like workaround. Inside

> tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

```
let xCoord = cell.pageBadgeView.center.x - cell.pageBadgeView.frame.origin.x
let yCoord = cell.pageBadgeView.center.y - cell.pageBadgeView.frame.origin.y

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: xCoord ,y: yCoord), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
```

pageBadgeView is basically the UIView that is supposed to be the reference point for the drawing circle.

My question is:

**Why don't just use center.x and center.y, why did I have to substract values of center and origin to get the middle coordinate?**

Comment: If you just want a circle view have you try with `cornerRadious` with `UIView`

Comment: Yes that's another approach, my question is rather more about curiosity why did I have to substract center and origin to actually get the center?

Comment: @DCDC, that is because when the code is being executed, in runtime, the views are initialized at the origin of cell (the superview). They get drawn at specified coords only after compilation. See my answer for cleaner approach. or you must hardcode the values of pageBadgeView's center in arccenter, that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

var someName = UIView()
var someNameRadius = 25.0
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("experienceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

someName.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
someName.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
someName.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
someName.center = cell.contentView.center
someName.frame.size = CGSize(width: someNameRadius*2, height: someNameRadius*2)
someName.layer.cornerRadius = someNameRadius  // Note, this is half of the width of the view's width
cell.contentView.addSubView(someName)


return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw circle take `UIView`. Set `Corner radius of layer` property of View. Set `color` for layer.

Modify your code in swift accordingly.

```
 let yCoord = (cellheight - circleview height)/2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like for making your view circle

```
_circleView.layer.cornerRadius = _circleView.frame.size.width/2;
_circleView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
_circleView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
_circleView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I guess it's down-voted because the code is uncommented and also variables name are unrelated with the ones in the question. It could be fine if you were instantiating them in the code but at this moment it looks like a copy-paste instead of an elaborated answer to the user question.